# Hartung-Knapp-Sidik-Jonkman variance correction in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, heterogeneity, reml

I am doing a meta-analysis of continuous data (SMD), number of studies (k) around 75, heterogeneity high (Tau-squared around 0.15, I-sqr over 75%). Our interest is in fact in a key subgroup analysis (k 50 and 14 for each subgroup). Average sample size is around 120 (intervention and control group combined), but there are quite a few small studies. 
I am using the REML meta-analysis model, is there any scope for also using Hartung-Knapp-Sidik-Jonkman variance correction? Could you point me to some references that discuss this?
Thank you!

Comment: Please do not cross-post to other lists until you are sure nobody is going to respond here. You already have an excellent response on the R-sig-meta-analysis list.

Comment: ... which is here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2020-May/002110.html

Comment: I am sorry about this, I posted almost simultaneously on the two listservs, did not realize it would cause confusion. Thank you for the answer.